# The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types 'Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.ExDateTime

Tags: ms-office, odata, office365

I'm trying to retrieve events for a user from its Office 365 account using the REST API but filtered by the field "LastModifiedTime". For instance, retrieve all the events that will happen after the date: '2014-09-19T03:45:30.4020439Z' or '2014-09-18T04:05:00Z' but i'm always retrieving this error message:

```
{
 "error": { 
   "code":"ErrorInternalServerError", 
   "message":"The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types
    ' Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.ExDateTime' and 'System.DateTimeOffset'.",
   "innererror":{ 
     "message":"The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types 
          'Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.ExDateTime' and 'System.DateTimeOffset'.",
     "type":"System.InvalidOperationException", 
     "stacktrace":" at 
          System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetComparisonOperator(ExpressionType 
          binaryType, String opName, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean 
          liftToNull)\r\n at 
          System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression left, 
          Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)\r\n at 
          Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.DataEntityFilterConverter.ConvertFilterNode(QueryNode queryNode)\r\n at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.DataEntityFilterConverter.
          ConvertFilterClause(FilterClause filterClause)\r\n at 
          Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.DataEntityQueryAdpater.GetEntityQueryOptions()\r\n
          at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.FindEventsCommand.InternalExecute()\r\n at
          Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.Execute()\r\n at 
          Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataTask.Execute(TimeSpan 
          queueAndDelayTime, TimeSpan totalTime)" 
    }
  }
}
```

And here are urls:

```
/Me/Events?$select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=LastModifiedTime ge 2014-09-19T03:45:30.4020439Z

/Me/Events?$select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=LastModifiedTime ge 2014-09-18T04:05:00Z
```

I think my error is caused by the date format but i don't know how to solve it.

Could anybody help me on that, please!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting your date value to a datetimeoffset similar to below.

```
/Me/Events?$select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=LastModifiedTime ge datetimeoffset'2014-09-19T03:45:30.4020439Z'

/Me/Events?$select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=LastModifiedTime ge datetimeoffset'2014-09-18T04:05:00Z'
```

Or You could use the cast operation

```
/Me/Events?$select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=LastModifiedTime ge cast(2014-09-19T03:45:30.4020439Z, Edm.DateTimeOffset)

/Me/Events?$select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=LastModifiedTime ge cast(2014-09-18T04:05:00Z, Edm.DateTimeOffset)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I tried your suggest but this time show other error:
>{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQuery","message":"The query parameter '$filter' is invalid.","innererror":{"message":"The query parameter '$filter' is invalid."
>"message":"The child type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.

Comment: Did you try both options or just the cast. The first option should work on input strings

Comment: Thank you, I've tried both options. 
With the first option is the following error:
"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQuery","message":"The query parameter '$filter' is invalid."

Comment: When the filter under the Start, End under the url: 
/Me/Events?$Select=Subject,Start,End,LastModifiedTime&$filter=Start ge 2014-09-18T04:05:00Z
Data obtained as follows:

{
"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/$metadata#Me/Events",
"value":[
  {
  "@odata.id":"xxxxx",
  "@odata.editLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/xxxxxxx",
  "Id":"xxxxxx",
  "Subject":"Canceled: testttttt",
  "Start":"2014-09-24T08:30:00Z",
  "End":"2014-09-24T09:30:00Z",
  "LastModifiedTime":"2014-09-24T08:37:08.5438383Z",
  }
  ]
}: